# What are the descendants of the PIE suffix "-n̥kʷos" in the Czech language if there are any?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, slavic-languages, czech

Me and my friend would like to know whether there is any PIE suffix "-n̥kʷos" descendats in the czech language, we feel like "-uha" in "ostruha" could be it, in other slavic languages it is something like "Ostroga", we are not 100% sure though, so we would like to know more, so if you could confirm it, or tell us if anything else could be it, if it is not our example.

Comment: What is this PIE suffix? Can you give an example of its use?

Comment: I’m not familiar with any such suffix either. It would be a very unusual suffix for PIE.

Comment: Seems like it aims at https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/-ung%C5%8D  The OP also opened sever threads about this at Reddit and perhaps elsewhere. did you get any answer there? According to the linked wiki it is all unclear and nothing Slavic is mentioned.

Comment: @VladimirF I would be interested in some other sources of information, since wiktionary does not provide any more, no one gave me a conclusive answer in the other threads yet

Comment: I think in Proto-Slavic it should become something like -ęčь (> Chech -íč)